# Disable scrolling Safari 9 on Mac OS X

Tags: javascript, css, macos, safari

I am trying to disable the X scroll on Safari 9 (OS X El Capitan) with the following code, but it doesn't work, it works on Firefox and Chrome but Safari is still scrolling, anyone can help me?

My CSS code:

```
html, body
{
    overflow-x: hidden
}
```

My JavaScript code:

```
function disableX(e)
{
    if(scrollX > 0)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}
addEventListener("scroll", disableX);
```

Answer (score 0):

add position:relative; to body

```
body {
  position:relative;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

[More infos on: Safari Oveflow Hidden Problem](http://www.tonylea.com/2010/safari-overflow-hidden-problem/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding !important, otherwise open the chrome dev tools to see what property its using.

Answer (score 0):

But `overflow-x: hidden;`on `body`and `html`really doesn't make that much sense, i.e. if there *is* something else to see, a user should be able to see it, and I guess that's the reason Safari prevents it.

Maybe you should apply that setting to some element a bit further down in the DOM hierarchy.

---> Edited part: What I meant is: Erase those rules from `body`and `html`, put an DIV in there directly inside `<body>` (i.e. a wrapper for everything) and apply your overflow-rule to that DIV.

Comment: I need it to the body, because in the body i have 5 sections with width 100vw and i need to scroll these sections by using JavaScript and not scrollbars, i need to disable the default X scroll.

Comment: Well, I mean a wrapper around these 5 sections. In this case the wrapper would have 100% height, i.e. there would be nothing to scroll in the body. Scrolling would have to happen inside that wrapper, and you can prevent it with ``overflow-x: hidden;`The Javascript scolling would have to happen within that wrapper...